# how to get value/text from a OptionSet?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am creating a web resource which will populate a HTML table with tasks
I was trying to get the `PriorityCode` of a tasks. But I don't know how to get value/text from a `OptionSet`.

This is a screen shot :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have query metadata, see this various methods to do that:

- http://crmdude.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/performing-a-javascript-web-service-call-to-the-metadata-service/
- http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/retrieving-optionset-lable-data-using.html
- http://mileyja.blogspot.pt/2011/08/retrieve-installed-language-packs-in_19.html

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the AttributeFormat member.  Check to see if this member contains a key for your OptionSet; if it does not, then Pedro's advice is probably the next place I would go.