# CRM Dynamics SDK how to access related data

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using early-bound entities, generated by CrmSvcUtil, and I'm testing the SDK by retrieving an account entity:-

```
var account = myContext.AccountSet.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == Guid.Parse("..."));
```

(BTW is there an easier way to retrieve an entity by ID?!)

Looking at the account object that is returned, I can see various properties of type `OptionSetValue` (e.g. "PreferredContactMethodCode"). How do I get the actual item from this OptionSetValue object?

Similarly, there are numerous properties of type `EntityReference`, which contains an Id and LogicalName (the entity name I presume). How can I populate such a property - is it one of the Get... methods? And do these have to be called separately, or is it possible to "pre-fetch" certain relationships as part of the initial query that retrieves the account entity?

Similarly with the various IEnumerable<> properties (which presumably correspond to 1-M entity relationships), e.g. a property called "opportunity_customer_accounts" of type IEnumerable. How do I populate one of these properties? And (again) does this have to be done as a separate query/method call, or can it be "pre-fetched"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Retrieve**

I'm not really sure how much simpler the retrieve operation could get but for a single record the user of the context is probably overkill. So you could retrieve a specific record where you know directly with the IOrganizationService:

`account = service.Retrieve("account", Guid.Parse("..."), new ColumnSet(true));`

**Option Set Labels**

For the OptionSet labels you can look at my answer here: [How to get the option set from a field in an entity in CRM 2011 using crm sdk and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324096/how-to-get-the-option-set-from-a-field-in-an-entity-in-crm-2011-using-crm-sdk-an/23354017#23354017).

If you need the label for multiple OptionSet's on an entity you may want to just retrieve the Entity's metadata once (http://srinivasrajulapudi.blogspot.com/2012/01/retrieve-entity-metadata-in-crm-2011.html):

```
string entityName ="contact";

// Get the metadata for the currently list's entity
// This metadata is used to create a "Property Descriptor Collection"
RetrieveEntityRequest mdRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest ( )
{ EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
LogicalName = entityName,
RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
};

// Execute the request
RetrieveEntityResponse entityResponse = ( RetrieveEntityResponse ) this.ServiceProxy.Execute ( mdRequest );

EntityMetadata entityData = entityResponse.EntityMetadata;



//To Get Option Set Data
var preferdList= ( entityData.Attributes.Where ( p => p.LogicalName == "preferredcontactmethodcode" ) ).ToList ( ).FirstOrDefault ( ); ;

if ( preferdList != null ) {

PicklistAttributeMetadata optionList= preferdList as PicklistAttributeMetadata;
OptionSetMetadata opValues= optionList.OptionSet;
foreach ( var op in opValues.Options ) {

preferedMethod.Add ( new OptionSet { Value = op.Value.Value, Text = op.Label.LocalizedLabels[0].Label.ToString() } );
}

}
```

**EntityReference()**
To set an EntityReference typed field:

`account.primarycontact = new EntityReference("contact", Guide.Parse("..."));`

If they have a value and you requested the column in your `ColumnSet()` they should be populated, so I'm not really sure I understand your question. If you mean, you want the full record then you need to do a `service.Retrieve(...)` for the record.

**Related Entities (i.e., opportunity_customer_accounts)**

This is where using an `OrganizationServiceContext` makes life easier (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695791.aspx):

context.LoadProperty(contact, "transactioncurrency_contact");

// read related entity dynamically
var currency = contact.GetRelatedEntity("transactioncurrency_contact");
Console.WriteLine(currency.GetAttributeValue("currencyname"));

// read related entity statically
var currencyStatic = contact.transactioncurrency_contact;
Console.WriteLine(currencyStatic.CurrencyName);

If you are not using an `OrganizationServiceContext` you can try using a QueryExpression using `LinkedEntities`, although I've never done this to populate an early-bound entity so I don't know if it works (perhaps someone will add a comment with the answer.)