# C# - Set CRM OptionSetValue using only the string name of the option

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

Is it possible to set a new OptionSetValue with a Dynamics CRM using only the name / label of  the option?

For example, I have the following OptionSet:

```
1 : Male
2 : Female
```

If I don't have the `int` value, is it possible to use the `string` label instead? Such as...

```
my_optionSet = new OptionSetValue(Male)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use `enum` to achieve it.

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 864630000,
    Female = 864630001,    
};

my_optionSet = new OptionSetValue((int)Gender.Male);
```

These are going to be pre-defined key:value pairs that never changes between environments. When you think about avoiding code deployments & refined to schema solution only deployments whenever new options getting added in that attribute, you can invest on [Retrieve OptionSet Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23324096/7920473).

Comment: This is by far the best solution

Comment: Nicely done, thanks! This still leaves the question of *if I dont know the int value...* outstanding, but I think I can work around this.

Comment: @ArunVinoth, Dont know how i never even considered using the service! thanks

Comment: @Klicker :) it happens for all of us

Answer (score 3):

In your case I would use a  `Dictionary<string, int>` be a mapper table then you can pass your string value then set then `int` parameter in `OptionSetValue` class.

```
Dictionary<string, int> mapperT = new Dictionary<string, int>();
mapperT.Add("Male", 1);
mapperT.Add("Female", 2);
my_optionSet = new OptionSetValue(mapperT["Male"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Arun answer. You can generate the Early-Bound classes and get the options set generated for you. There is a tool in the XrmToolbox for this:

[image]